# How do you define and import a class type in flow?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Is is possible to define a class type in a file, which gets explicitly imported in another?

for example:

`types.js`

```
export type MyType {
  id: number,
  name: string,
};

declare class MyOject {
  constructor(): MyObject;
  getStuff(param: number): MyType;
  ...
}
```

`main.js`

```
import type {MyObject, MyType} from './types.js'; // <- flow does now recognize MyObject
....
```

I want to be able to import it like in `main.js` but this violates flow since it doesn't recognize `MyObject` as a valid import.

I've tried a few different solutions to no success:

- changing `declare class` to `export class` results in flow errors
- moving 'types.js' to a flow library folder means that I will have to import it from a flow module rather than the file itself.  This breaks this files dependency on the flow types file.

Is there a way to define a flow class type and import it explicitly from the file it's defined in?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`declare export class`](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-an-es-module):

Types.js

```
// @flow
export type MyType = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

declare export class MyObject {
  constructor(): void;

  getStuff(param: number): MyType;
}
```

Main.js

```
// @flow
import {MyObject} from './types.js'
import type { MyObject as MyObjectType, MyType } from './types.js'

const newObj: MyObjectType = new MyObject()
```

As a repo: https://github.com/jameskraus/flow-exporting-declared-class